# In editableTextAngular directive the text container goes to infinity in edit mode

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, textangular

I'm using text-angular with [editableTextAngular](https://gist.github.com/jordanburke/9532bf28f884802d4055) directive in a angular xeditable form and when entering in edit mode the text container goes to infinity.

This is my CSS:

```
.ta-editor {
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin:20px 0;
}
```

View Mode & Edit Mode:
[In view mode it is shown correctly. In edit mode the text container goes outside the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOyJU.png)

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;">
  <span
      editable-text-angular="notificacion.texto"
      data-e-name="notificacion.texto"
      data-e-class="editable-text-angular"
      ng-bind-html="notificacion.texto"
  >
      {{notificacion.texto}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what class is applied to the input field?

Comment: jsfiddle if possible please

Comment: Set a specific width for the input field so it does not go to infinity. There is nothing much i can say without a js fiddle